# Синхронное выполнение асинхронного кода при обращении к chrome.storage

Tags: chrome-extension, async-await, storage

В API chrome имеется функция сохранения каких-либо данных - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

- `chrome.storage.local...` - данные располагаются локально.
- `chrome.storage.sync...` - данные синхронизируется на устройствах с таким же аккаунтом google.

Оба способа выполняются асинхронно. Хотелось изменить это. Однако не понимаю, как =(

```
// Не работает

(async () => {
  await chrome.storage.local.get('config', data => {
    console.log('first 111');
  });

  console.log('END 222');
})();
```

**Конкретный вопрос:** возможно ли дождаться завершения запроса (chrome.storage...) без использования callback'ов и лишь после вывести "END 222"?

**З.ы.** Про `localStorage` знаю, но хотелось разобраться с `chrome.storage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конструкции вида `async` и `await` являются синтаксическим сахаром для использования с промисами (Promise) и в случае ассинхронного коллбэка не могут быть использованы.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос: нет, к сожалению не получится без использования callback.

Однако, вы можете сделать обертку с промисом:

```js
(async () => {
    // Обертка над chrome.storage.local
    async function getValue(name) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            chrome.storage.local.get(name, data => {
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }

    // Получение значения
    const data = await getValue('config');
    console.log(data);
})();
```